# Include CSS and Javascript Plugins in Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, plugins

I'm using a HTML, CSS, JS template to create the view for my Rails application. This template requires some plug-ins (mixed between CSS and JS files). I put these plug-ins in "/assets/plugins/" folders and make the call

```
<script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = 'assets/plugins/';</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.js"></script>
```

and it does not work. 
How can I call these plug-ins from my *.html.erb file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<%= javascript_include_tag 'path_to_your_js_file' %>` for js. 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "path_to_your_css_file" %>` for css.

Comment: Yes, but I have more than 10 plug-ins and this turns out an inefficient way. Is there any general method to do this?

Comment: Each plugin might have their own way of inclusion. Please read the documentation of each plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them into `vendor/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, and call them in `application.js` and `application.css` by `//= require your.plugin` in `application.js` and `*= require your.plugin` in `application.css`. After that restart your server.